# Case insensitive function to delete rows containing keyword

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I run a script in Google Sheets to remove rows that have certain keywords.  The code is as follows:

```
    function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];

    if (row[0].indexOf("robot") > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
}
```

The function here will delete the row that contains the keyword 'robot'.  Except if the content is "Robot", the script will not delete the row.  Can someone instruct me on how to make this function case insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `toLowerCase()` JavaScript String toLowerCase() Method
i did some modification on your script here is
it do that work just for column A you can change it

```
function removeKeywords() {
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
          //Change 'A' with your target column
          var values = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
          for (var i = values.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
            if (values[i][0].toLowerCase().indexOf("robot") > -1) {
              sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Chemiadel.  Is it possible to run the script irrespective of the column?  Our values appear either in column A or B.  Also, what if I have two or three terms, rather than just one, that I want to mark for deletion.  Say that I want to delete all instances of "robot", "admin", and "class".